# Is it possible to show multiple plots in separate windows?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Hello I am plotting a function 10 times and also printing the separate values. 
I also wanted to plot all the 10 cases separately in separate windows.

So I created a new `for loop` for the plotting which is still plotting just the first instance and once I close the first one, only then I can see the second one.

I also tried to use `plt.hold(true)`.

Here is what I tried to do-

```
def signal():
    t1 = np.random.choice(candidates)
    t2 = np.random.choice(candidates)
    t3 = np.random.choice(candidates)
    t4 = np.random.choice(candidates)
    t5 = np.random.choice(candidates)
    y = a * np.exp(-t /t1) + a * np.exp(-t /t2) + a * np.exp(-t /t3) + a * np.exp(-t /t4) + a * np.exp(-t /t5)
return y

for i in range(nsets):
    signalset = []
    signalset.append(signal())
    print(signal())

for i in range (nsets):
    plt.plot(t, signal())
    plt.show()
    plt.hold(True)
```

Is there any way I could generate 10 plots simultaneously in 10 different windows?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Figures have an index `plt.figure(n)` where `n` is a number starting at **`1`**.
This allows to later activate an already created figure to plot new stuff to it, but it also allows create several figures in a loop.

In order to show all images simultaneously, use plt.show() at the very end.
In this case you'd do

```
for i in range(10):
    plt.figure(i+1) #to let the index start at 1
    plt.plot(t, signal())
plt.show()
```

This create all 10 windows at the end of the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new figure windows by specifying a new figure index, for example `plt.figure(10)`. In your case you can use:

```
for i in range (nsets):
    plt.figure(i) # choose figure i to be the current figure (create it if not already existing)
    plt.plot(t, signal())
    plt.show()
    plt.hold(True)
```

Comment: so Is it like for 10 different figures i should do plt.figure(1), pt.figure(2).... and so on?